# Appendix before references when asked for separate page of references

Tags: formatting

I'm submitting to a conference, which has the following text in the call for papers:

> Papers must be submitted in PDF format according to ACM guidelines and
>   style files to fit within X pages including any diagrams and
>   appendices, plus up to 1 additional page of references.

The ACM style files have the references before the appendix, but this text makes it seem like the references should be separate. How would you arrange the references and the appendix? Which would be placed first?

Answer (score 3):

I think the order of mentioning the differenct sections does not resemble their order in the document. The way I read it, the journal only wants to clarify that the one page with references does not count into the X pages for all the other stuff. While I can't give you a source here, from personal experience the appendix comes after the references. That's just the way it usually works.